# stackoverflow exception with htmlagility pack

Tags: stack-overflow, html-agility-pack

I am using the htmlagilitypack to parse an xml document. I use it to load the string as a htmldocument and then use the xmltextreader to parse. I will occasionally get an unhandled stackoverflow exception on htmlagility.dll.
The specific line is

```
internal Dictionary<string, Htmlattribute> Hashitems = new 
                            Dictionary<string, HtmlAttribute>()
```

EDIT:

```
Try
            Dim hdoc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
            hdoc.LoadHtml(xmlsnippet)
            Dim nreader As XmlTextReader = New 
                         XmlTextReader(New StringReader(xmlsnippet))
            Dim ncount As Integer = 0

            While nreader.Read
                If Not nreader.Name = "" Then
                    ncount += 1
                    If ncount = 18 Then
                        Exit While
                    End If
                    num += 1
                    nodelist.Add(nreader.Name)
                    If nreader.Name = "id" Then
                        statid = nreader.ReadInnerXml
                    End If
                    If nreader.Name = "published" Then
                        contentDate = nreader.ReadInnerXml
                        contentDate = Regex.Replace(contentDate, "T", " ")
                        contentDate = Regex.Replace(contentDate, "\+", " ")
                        contentDate = contentDate.Replace("Z", "")
                    End If
                    If nreader.Name = "summary" Then
                        ctext = nreader.ReadInnerXml
                    End If
                    If nreader.Name = "title" Then
                        csubject = nreader.ReadInnerXml
                        If csubject.Contains("posted") Then
                            template = csubject
                            author = Regex.Replace(template, "posted.*", "")
                        End If
                        If csubject.Contains("Keyword -") Then
                          Dim tip As String = csubject
                            searchterm = 
                            Regex.Replace(csubject, "xxxxxx.*xxxxxx.*xxxx.*-", "")
                            searchterm = 
                           Regex.Replace(searchterm, "xxxxx.*xxxxxx.*Search.*-", "")
                            Trim(searchterm)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End While

            Dim mreader As XmlTextReader = 
                        New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(xmlsnippet))
            Dim mcount As Integer = 0

            While mreader.Read
                If Not mreader.Name = "" Then
                    mcount += 1
                    If mcount > 15 Then
                        If mreader.Name = "uri" Then
                            authorUri = mreader.ReadInnerXml
                            Trim(authorUri)
                            If authorUri = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/" Then
                                authorUri = ""
                            End If
                        End If
                        If mreader.Name = "name" Then
                            author = mreader.ReadInnerXml
                            If author = "xxxxxx" Then
                                author = ""
                            End If
                        End If
                        If mreader.Name = "content" Then
                            htext = mreader.ReadInnerXml
                        End If
                        If mreader.Name = "link" Then
                            Dim address As String
                            address = mreader.ReadOuterXml
                            If address.Contains("related") Then
                                Dim regex12 As Regex =
            New Regex("<link.*rel.*href=""(?<Link>.*?)"".*/>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                                Dim m12 As Match = regex12.Match(address)
                                himage = m12.Groups("Link").Value
                            ElseIf address.Contains("alternate") Then
                                Dim regex13 As Regex = 
           New Regex("<link.*rel.*href=""(?<Link>.*?)"".*/>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                                Dim m13 As Match = regex13.Match(address)
                                authorUri = m13.Groups("Link").Value
                            End If
                        End If
                        If mreader.Name = "subtitle" Then
                            hsubtitle = mreader.ReadInnerXml
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            appLogs.constructLog(ex.Message.ToString, True, True)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
```

In fact there are different stackoverflow exception errors occurring at different lines but the same error and only while using htmlagilitypack. I am in another method trying to parse the xml using xmldocument, xpathnavigator and it works fine unless I get some bad xml, then I go to this method. I have set up exception catches to just move the bad xml to a folder and then exit this method but I cannot catch these kinds of exceptions or can I?

Another line where error shows:

```
public string Name
{
   get
   {
     if (_name == null)
     {
       Name = _ownerdocument.Text.Substring(_namestartindex, _namelength);
     }
      return _name != null ? _name.ToLower() : string.Empty;
```

on the last line in the snippet above in the file HtmlNode.cs.
The call stack window shows the top as

```
HtmlAgilityPack.dll!HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.Name.get() Line 432 + 0x21 bytes
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see your code (preferrably, with input data) which throws this exception